Need to install Visual Studio in OFFLINE MODE
I have used the online visual studio chat and they said install a ticket. Two days later I got a new person and they just went around in circles and said create a ticket. So that is what I am doing.   I have followed the pages below to download and create the repository.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
I then moved about 29 GB of files from where I downloaded to the spot I needed to install.
Then I ran commands from the repository directory on the offline machine to try to install Visual Studio. I have tried a variety of commands like
vc_community.exe  --noWeb and others.   it will come up and load the installer, then ask to continue, then another continue and then the download screen where it has two horizontal progress lines.    see below repository for these pictures i uploaded to the support.
https://support.microsoft.com/files?workspace=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgxMTA4NjE5MTQzMTQ1NTc0QUYxMjI3NjhGMEIzNDkyRkYyNTczNEYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJ3c2lkIjoiOTdmZTc4ZjYtYmFhZS00MjdmLTgyYTYtNzVjMTI1YzgxZDI3Iiwic3IiOiIyNDA4MDcwMDQwMDEwNDM1Iiwic3YiOiJ2MSIsInJzIjoiRXh0ZXJuYWwiLCJ3dGlkIjoiNTlmYTcwM2MtZjhlYi00MjkwLThiZjYtNDIyOWM2ZThjMGY5IiwiYXBwaWQiOiI0ZTc2ODkxZC04NDUwLTRlNWUtYmUzOC1lYTNiZDZlZjIxZTUiLCJuYmYiOjE3MjMwNTU3NDIsImV4cCI6MTczMDgzMTc0MiwiaWF0IjoxNzIzMDU1NzQyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5kdG1uZWJ1bGEubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zbWMifQ.mCEnHViv7h6rrFYpYKNVEQ1PU30YyDAof6b3ZcOxqMm2CR8vlG3T2i5DCqu9fQFMFaCy4_aWeEPSC7xpfQ5OPl-FBBdUqGU6exYMZOVxLMFqXy58iLDoWgNS1ODcq-q5ceSGqVNE8YuFUuIJxt1Ntyt6g_dcezO-wlXPfB03xvbOy1aWCdx_91MrqI5ShjxoZ64nAf0Lnua2iREgLWDS4ns-BY4HhRsAzuwyr8Ao4T71VTPhUEVMwIJ9ORJbLd7gdDpQxNJJzcX2RwKUhd38s99YUkHi3KKuRFNvv6zKocDwJsrfG-louLk1NOFQA438J2byPO-lBg-A9cn5ols_DQ&wid=97fe78f6-baae-427f-82a6-75c125c81d27
from reading the internet i found the install log file and it looks like it is still trying to go to the internet to get files. and then fails after not getting files for 5-10 minutes.
How do I get vs community to install?
I contacted TWO separate online chats and they both failed and both said it needs to be a ticket to get someone to figure this out . I expect to get visual studio installed

It seems that i am unable to access to your support link, could you please share these pictures on SO? Besides, you said you have found the installation log files, please share them to help us do further investigation to figure out why it still try go to the internet to get files even you use --noWeb.
